# form.reset() of jquery-form-validator issue

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form as below which I validate using this **[validator](http://formvalidator.net/)** plugin:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 form-contact">
    <form action="/Home/SendMessage" id="contact-form" method="post" autocomplete="off" class="wow bounceInUp has-validation-callback animated">
     //..All other form controls

    </form>
</div>
```

but when I tried to `reset` the `form` as below

```
$('form#contact-form').reset();
```

OR

```
$('#contact-form').reset();
```

it gave me console.error
**`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function`**

but when I try to `reset` the form as below it resets perfectly.

```
$('.form-contact form').get(0).reset();
```

Can anyone tell why this is happening or what is the reason behind this?

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$('#contact-form')` retuns the form in an **array of the object**. In this case array of form object with length 1.
Write that in browser console and see what happens.

the `reset()` is a **native javascript function** which requires specific `form` object which the selector doesn't provide without `$('#contact-form')[0]`

use `$('#contact-form')[0].reset();` which gets `first form` from the array.

[image]

try **console.log($("#contact-form"));** in the console. then you can see the result by expanding the object.

Comment: Your explanation seems legitimate but one more doubt here! When we refer a `form` with its `id` it should return the form object itself right? Any idea why `array of object` is returned?

Comment: the jQuery selector always returns in an array, which in case of textboxes give value of the 1st object in array with `$(..).val()`, but doesn't work with `forms` the same way

Comment: Is there any specific reason for the same not to work with form??

Comment: Great!! Got my answer!! :) Thank you for your time.. :)